# Function to check number in mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a random number exists in mysql

```
$newEventId = rand(1000, 10000);
EventId($newEventId);

function EventId($gen)
{

  if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE EventID=$gen" )) == 0) 
    break;

  // recall function
  else 
  {
    $newEventId = rand(1000, 10000);
    EventId($newEventId);
  } 
}

//insert into events table
```

Comment: Ok. What specifically is the question?

Comment: @UnholyRanger the question is in the title. But what does `EventId()` do/mean?

Comment: What's with the `break` statement after the `if`? It makes no sense. And it seems like you're missing an opening `{`.

Comment: @MathieuImbert No. All braces are correct.

Comment: ITT, How do you know that the function *is **not** working*?

Comment: @DreamEater You are right I was confused by the indentation.

Comment: shouldn't $gen be '$gen' - quoted? Also, maybe instead of break you should cause and action, echo, call function etc..

Comment: @SmithSmithy `$gen` is an integer, it doesn't need quotes.

Comment: @SmithSmithy No quotes required for comparing integers/numbers.

Comment: Isn't the function supposed to be declared before it is called?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `AUTO_INCREMENT` column instead trying to generate "random" id? Also, `EventId` function is not safe as choosing a id and storing it in database is not atomic so another process may already used same id.

If table has `event_id` column created as `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` SQL should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (event_id, ...) VALUES (<everything EXCEPT event_id>);
event_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't state why it's `not working`, but my guess is that in `//insert into events table` code below your are using the `$newEventId` in the `INSERT`, and it works fine if the initial `$newEventId` causes `(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE EventID=$gen" )) == 0)` to return `true`, but not if it returns `true` on the recursive function.

Try returning the value on the `break` and using that instead of `$newEventId`

```
function EventId($gen)
{

  if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE EventID=$gen" )) == 0) {
  return $gen; // return the number that will be set as $EventId and used in the insert
  break;
  }
  // recall function
  else 
  {
    $newEventId = rand(1000, 10000);
    EventId($newEventId);
  } 
}

$newEventId = rand(1000, 10000);
$EventId = EventId($newEventId);  // set the returned $gen to $EventId to be used in the Insert query

//insert into events table
mysql_query("INSERT INTO events ... EventID=$EventId..");
```